# Set/get методы для приватного поля

Tags: getter, java, setter

Нужно ли следуя практике хорошего тона программирования создавать приватные методы доступа set/get для приватных полей класса, доступ к которым из вне запрещен?

```
private String msg;

private setMsg(String m) { this.msg = m; }
private String getMsg() { return this.msg; }
```

или даже лучше напрямую внутри класса изменять значение данного поля?

```
private void foo() {
    ...
    this.msg = "bar";
    ...

}
```

Comment: Приватные геттер и сеттер смысла не имеют

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Приватные геттеры/сеттеры избыточны. Не нужно.

Comment: есть ситуации, когда они очень полезны. Например, нужно отслеживать обращение к полю. С помощью геттера/сеттера это делается легко. С обычным полем нужно делать кучу кода.

Вариант два. Нужно, чтобы значения некого поля всегда соответствовал определенным правилам. Если это просто поле - нужно вставлять проверки и следить. Если у поля есть сеттер, то вся проверка уходит в сеттер.

Comment: Ни один из ваших доводов не говорит в пользу того, что это нужно делать ВСЕГДА. Естественно в случае нужды их можно добавить. Несколько раз перечитал ваш комментарий, и так и не понял его смысла)

Comment: а я не утверждаю, что это геттеры/сеттеры нужны всегда. Они нужны иногда.

А то, что Вы не поняли смысла, это уже не ко мне.

Answer (score 1):

В целом, оба подходы имеют место быть, даже Мартин Фаулер в книге "Рефакторинг" говорит, что есть ярые фанаты обоих подходов, но единения нет. По поводу сеттеров/геттеров удобно в небольших классах, а вот вдруг вы рефакторите какой-нибудь класс, большой, с большим количеством полей и все дела, то вы чекнетесь от этих геттеров/сеттеров.

**Обновление**

Есть такая практика, называть приватные поля начиная с подчеркивания `"private String _msg;"`, так что сразу понятно в коде, где приватное поле/метод, а где нет.

Если вам надо обратиться к приватному полю извне - то надо делать геттер, если вы будете общаться с полем внутри класса - геттеры/сеттеры не нужны. Вот так =) Но если получается так, что у вас надо ко ВСЕМ приватным полям обращаться извне, то у вас ошибка в архитектуре, и скорее всего класс занимается не тем чем надо и надо делать рефакторинг и делегировать обязанности в другие классы/методы.

Comment: @ua6xh, неужели даже для приватных полей, к которым не будет доступа из вне даже через get метод такие разногласия?

Comment: @ua6xh чтобы не чокнуться от setters/getters, есть lombok.